# I can’t log in, how to reset password macbook m1

Tags: password, login, administrator, screen-lock

the password is wrong it shows but I have taken the pic of the password last night [image] [image]

Comment: You have set a password consisting of 31 random characters as your login password?

Comment: I set it for my admin I don’t know it was the same for log in

Comment: Did you set an Admin user and a "User" user? I always have an admin account separate to my "general" use account. Saves a lot of issues.

Comment: Yes. I thought the same now. Just set different accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset password for macbook m1 (icloud password needed) press power button until shut down then before the keyboard on and in case in turn on again before logo appeared or opening sound we press power button for long time until the logo appear and said continue holding for start up option

For details, have a look at the related [support article from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212190) or at [this video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=pXiqUwB0piE&si=EnSIkaIECMiOmarE).